# Clickaway gets triggered twice on one click

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I want to create a filter component where i can pass filter options down to my child component. I put on every filter an click event to open the filter so the user can chosse the options and an `v-on-clickaway` when the user clicks away so the options closes
This is how my child component looks like:

```
        <div
          v-for="filter in filters"
          id="desktop-menu-0"
          class="relative inline-block text-left"
          @click="toggle(filter.id, true)"
          v-on-clickaway="toggle(filter.id, false)"
        >...</div>
```

Here the script:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway'

export type FilterOptionT = {
  text: string
  value: unknown
  selected: boolean
}
export type FilterT = {
  id: any
  text: string
  open: boolean
  values: FilterOptionT[]
}
export default {
  mixins: [clickaway],
  props: {
    filters: {
      default: () => [] as FilterT[],
    },
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    function toggle(id: any, state: boolean) {
      emit('toggleFilter', id, state)
    }

    return { toggle }
  },
}
</script>
```

Here my parent component:

```
<filterVue @toggleFilter="toggleFilter" :filters="filters"></filterVue>

let filters = ref<FilterT[]>([
  {
    open: false,
    text: paths.members_table.status,
    id: 'status',
    values: [
      {
        selected: false,
        text: paths.statustexts.accepted,
        value: Userstatus.ACCEPTED,
      },
      {
        selected: false,
        text: paths.statustexts.asked,
        value: Userstatus.WAIT,
      },
      {
        selected: false,
        text: paths.statustexts.activated_eda,
        value: Userstatus.MC_ACTIVATED,
      },
    ],
  },
])

function toggleFilter(filterId: any, state: boolean) {
  console.log(state, filterId)
  let filterIndex = filters.value.findIndex((f) => f.id === filterId)
  if (filterIndex !== -1) {
    filters.value[filterIndex].open = state
  }
}
```

When i click now on my element it shows me 3 logs in my console:

[image]

It instantly closes it, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not use a `toggle` method, but instead directly mutate the `close` property of your filters, like so:

```html
<div
   v-for="filter in filters"
   id="desktop-menu-0"
   class="relative inline-block text-left"
   @click="filter.open = true"
   v-on-clickaway="filter.open = false"
>...</div>
```

Secondly, I think the console output you see is linked to `v-on-clickaway`. Maybe it's not working properly, and it bubbles up?
I would suggest using another library such as [onClickOutside](https://vueuse.org/core/onClickOutside/) from [VueUse](https://vueuse.org/)

UPDATE

Just saw something that could explain your issue: you assign the same id `desktop-menu-0` to all your filters. Try assigning a unique id to each of them.